# Android Studio - how does setImageDrawable work?

Tags: android, imageview

I've been trying to teach myself how to use android studio but I've hit a road block, whats wrong with this code? It wont let me use a draw-able to be set as the image?

```
    public void obama(){
    Switch s = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.obamaswitch);
    s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView p = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.obamahere);
            p.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.brock);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Use the `ImageView#setImageResource()` method if you want to pass a Resource ID directly. Otherwise, load the Drawable from Resources with the `getDrawable()` method first, before passing it in the `setImageDrawable()` method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to know what is a parameter and the difference between `setImageDrawable` and `setImageResource`.

Different methods requires different parameters. And by that I mean different *types* of parameters. In this case, `setImageDrawable` requires a parameter of type `Drawable` but you gave it a parameter of type `int`. So that's why it doesn't work.

I don't know if you know this. All the resource ids (i.e. the `R.xxx.xxx` thingy) in Android are integers! So when you try to pass an integer when it actually needs a `Drawable`, it fails to do so, of course.

What you need is to either

1) Find a method that accepts an integer as a parameter. or;

2) Use the resource id to get a `Drawable` object.

For 1), you can use the `setImageResource` method. Just replace the word `Drawable` with `Resource` and change nothing else!

If you prefer 2), you can use this method to get the drawable using a resource id.

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(<insert your id here>);
```

And then you can pass `myDrawable` as the parameter:

```
p.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Answer (score 4):

getResources().getDrawable() deprecated API 22. You should use

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.name_icon)
```

or

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.name_icon, null)
```

Comment: yes it's deprecated API 22. just add ,null

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
p.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brock));
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the "brock" image in the drawable folder and replace this line

```
p.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.brock);
```

with:

```
p.setImageResource(R.drawable.brock);
```